# Writing formula in excel 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to make a sheet read all past bill data from a main rundown. In order to do this, I need to have one cell copy the date and keep it even after I change the original date, and then have the next cell read the next data and so on.

So on `Sheet 1` I have a date for the bill so `Sheet 1` `Cell B3`

I put a `Date 2-1-14` I want `Sheet 2` `Cell B2` to copy this date and then when the next months bill arrives I would change `Sheet 1` `Cell B3` from 2-1-14 to 3-1-14.

But I want `Sheet 2` `Cell B2` to stay 2-1-14 and have the next cell on `Sheet 2` `cell C3` to read the new date 3-1-14 and so forth.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new sheet for each month? When a new month starts, you create a new sheet, perhaps titled "Feb2014" or "2014Feb" or some such. Copy your formulas from previous month, and clear out the entered values.

Comment: I agree.  Making a new sheet is much simpler; unless you need some added functionality.